# Specify raw body of a POST request with Guzzle

Tags: php, http, guzzle

With Guzzle (version 3), I'd like to specify the body of a POST request in "raw" mode. I'm currently trying this:

```
$guzzleRequest = $client->createRequest(
    'POST',
    $uri,
    null,
    'un=one&deux=two'
);
```

But it kind of doesn't work. If I dump my `$guzzleRequest` I can see that `postFields->data` is empty. Using `$guzzleRequest->setBody()` afterwards doesn't help.

However if I specify the body as `['un'=>'one', 'deux'=>'two']`, it works as expected.

How can I specify the body of the request as `'un=one&deux=two'`?

Answer (score 0):

First I would highly recommend that you upgrade to Guzzle 6 as Guzzle 3 is deprecated and EOL.

It has been a long time since I used Guzzle 3 but I do believe you want the following:

```
$request = $client->post(
    $uri,
    $header = [],
    $params = [
        'un' => 'one',
        'deux' => 'two',
]);

$response = $request->send();
```

Guzzle will automatically set the Content-Type header.

More information is available with the [Post Request Documentation](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle3/blob/master/docs/http-client/request.rst#post-requests).

In response to your comment:

```
$request = $client->post(
    $uri,
    $headers = ['Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'],
    EntityBody::fromString($urlencodedstring)
)
```

For this, reference: [EntityBody Source](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle3/blob/master/src/Guzzle/Http/EntityBody.php) and [RequestFactory::create()](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle3/blob/master/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/RequestFactory.php)

Comment: Thanks Shaun, but this does not answer my question. I want to pass in the body content as a raw urlencoded string, like `'un=one&deux=two'`

Comment: If I use `new EntityBody('un=one&deux=two')`, I get a `Stream must be a resource` error. If I use `EntityBody::factory('un=one&deux=two')`, I get no error, but it doesn't solve my initial problem, nothing show up in `$request->postFields->data`

Comment: *wipes blurry eyes* You could use EntityBody::factory() or EntityBody::fromString.

Comment: In Guzzlev3 (as you indicate within your original post), unless I am reading the source code incorrectly, there is no 'postFields' within https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle3/blob/master/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/Request.php or https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle3/blob/master/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/AbstractMessage.php  Are you certain that you are using Guzzle v3?