# Set raw POST request body in guzzle 6

Tags: php, guzzle6

Is it still possible to set the raw request body (XML data which was properly created at another place) in Guzzle 6 ?

This seems to not work anymore: [Specify raw body of a POST request with Guzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293841/specify-raw-body-of-a-post-request-with-guzzle)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible with Guzzle 6:

```
...
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$rawContent = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='us-ascii'?>
<slideshow>
    <slide type="all">
        <title>Overview</title>
    </slide>
</slideshow>
XML;

$request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request(
    'post',
    'https://httpbin.org/post',
    ['content-type' => 'text/xml'],
    $rawContent
);

$responce = $client->send($request);

print_r((string) $responce->getBody());
```

If you need to send raw form data you can use:

```
...
$request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request(
    'post',
    'https://httpbin.org/post',
    ['content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'],
    'a=1&b=2'
);
...
```

Comment: @Alex is it something you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

[Guzzle 6 docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html?highlight=raw#uploading-data)

Example 1:

```
// Provide the body as a string.
$r = $client->request('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/post', [
    'body' => 'raw data'
]);
```

Example 2:

```
// Provide an fopen resource.
$body = fopen('/path/to/file', 'r');
$r = $client->request('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/post', ['body' => $body]);
```